# Correct escaping of wildcard when using jq

Tags: bash, wildcards, escape-characters, json, jq

The command below works:

```
$ echo '{ "a": [ { "b": "1" }, { "b": "2" } ] }' | jq -r '.a[0].b'
1
```

But if I try to get the values of all the `b` elements under `a` I get the following error:

```
$ echo '{ "a": [ { "b": "1" }, { "b": "2" } ] }' | jq -r '.a[*].b'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '*' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.a[*].b   
jq: 1 compile error
```

How should I escape the wildcard? I've tried several variants without success.

Using wildcard as array index is a valid option according to [https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#:~:text=JSONPath%20is%20a%20query%20language,that%20need%20to%20be%20verified](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#:%7E:text=JSONPath%20is%20a%20query%20language,that%20need%20to%20be%20verified).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array iterator in `jq` is `.[]`. The asterisk character is not required. The following command should get you the intended output:

```
echo '{ "a": [ { "b": "1" }, { "b": "2" } ] }' | jq -r '.a[].b'
```

Result:

```
1
2
```

Further reference: [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters)

As to why the syntax is different, `jq` is a tool with its own syntax for querying. It is not based on the JSONPath standard.

Comment: Hm. I was so sure that it wouldn't be necessary to learn new syntax...